# Console log in MongoDB Shell

Tags: mongodb, function, mongo-shell

I want to write functions into MongoDB Shell like this:

```
var last = function(collection) { db[collection].find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).toArray(); }
```

But there is one problem. When I call `last()` function, it will make no output. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either use the JavaScript **[`print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)** function or the mongo specific **[`printjson()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo)** function which returns formatted JSON to actually log to output the result from the find method, for example:

```
var last = function(collection) { 
    var doc = db.getCollection(collection).find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).toArray(); 
    printjson(doc); 
};
last("test");
```